# Rails form not creating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have created a simple form to create an instance of a modle and for some reason it is not calling the create method in the controller.  Here is the form code:

```
<% @house.mates.each do |mate| %>
    <p><%= mate.name %></p>
<% end %>

<h2>Add a new mate:</h2>
<%= form_for @mate do |f| %> 
    <p><%= f.label "Name" %>
       <%= f.text_field :name %>
       <%= f.hidden_field :house_id %>
   </p>
   <%= f.submit "Submit", :action => :create %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
class MatesController < ApplicationController

  def new 
    @mate = Mate.new
  end

  def create 
    @mate = Mate.new(params[:mate])
    @mate.save
    redirect_to house_path(current_house)
  end

end
```

There is a many to one relationship between the Mate model and the House model... I am fairly new to rails but I have made other apps with similar forms, and I have never had this problem before.  I can create and save Mate objects in the console, and I am not getting any errors, so it seem that somehow the controller method is not being called.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you validate that house_id must be present? Do you notice that your mate object is not assigned house_id?

Comment: So, i accidentally gave old code for the view, the first line of the form is `<%= form_for :mate, :url => {:action => 'create'} do |f| %>` otherwise i get a nomethod error for "model_name".  I added a reference to the house as mentioned below, but still when I press submit, it clears the text field and nothing happens.  When I look at Mate.all in the console, nothing has been added.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if other things have no problem, your @mate object should be created. You just can't see it in house page because you have not associated @mate with house in your code.

In your form you referred `:house_id`, but this attribute is nil when you rendering the form.

The reason is you have not assigned it in controller.

In controller you need to initialize `@mate` from house object to have house_id inside it

```
def new
  @house = something
  @mate  = @house.mates.new  # Instead of Mate.new
end
```

Comment: The reason to use `@house.mates.new` instead of `@house.mates.build` is that `build` will add the empty mate to the collection and thus add an empty space in the view